# Issue with Date and Mongoose Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, date, mongoose

I'm facing the issue with the Mongoose official document founded [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/schemas.html).

```
import { Schema, Model, model } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  avatar?: string;
  created: Date;
}

const schema = new Schema<IUser, Model<IUser>, IUser>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: String,
  avatar: String,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

export const UserModel = model<IUser>('User', schema);
```

My problem is the `created` type in `IUser` is not the same as in `schema` and got the error:

```
Type '{ type: DateConstructor; default: () => number; }' is not assignable to type 'typeof SchemaType | Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown> | Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown>[] | readonly Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown>[] | Function[] | ... 6 more ... | undefined'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'DateConstructor' is not assignable to type 'Date | typeof SchemaType | Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown> | undefined'.
      Type 'DateConstructor' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof SchemaType': cast, checkRequired, set, getts(2322)
(property) created?: typeof SchemaType | Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown> | Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown>[] | readonly Schema<any, any, undefined, unknown>[] | Function[] | ... 6 more ... | undefined
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date.now()` is a function which returns `number`. Instead of it, try using `new Date()` only. Also need to make changes in the type of `createdAt` to `Number`.

In the given doc link, `createdAt` field type is `number` but here you have written `Date`.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  avatar?: string;
  createdAt: number;
}
```

OR

`createdAt` and `updatedAt` are timestamps which can be used directly without specifying in the schema.

```
const schema = new Schema<IUser, Model<IUser>, IUser>({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: String,
  avatar: String
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: Ah yes. I'm trying to change `created` to number but no luck. With your assistance, I find my solution, change type to Number instead of Date in schema

Comment: @ĐặngKiên great and better if you use timestamps option in the schema to set it automatically. It is best when you don't want to make field name changes.

Comment: @ĐặngKiên for JS, `number` but for schema it will be `Number`. Please consider accepting my ans. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working

```
 import { Schema,Document } from 'mongoose';
 export interface IUser {
     name: string;
     email: string;
    avatar?: string;
   created: Date;
}
const schema = new Schema<IUser>({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: String,
    avatar: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
```

});

```
export const UserModel = model<IUser>('User', schema);
```